# Unique collapsible text with single jQuery function

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using jQuery for the first time and I'm trying to track down the best way to show/hide portions of text multiple times throughout a page with a single function. I have around 30 "newsletters" from different staff members and want to show the first paragraph of each with the option to toggle the rest of each letter. Here's what I have worked out -

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
$('#toggle').click(function() {
    $('.toggle').toggle();
    return false;
});
});

$(function(){
   $(".collapse").click(function () {
   $(this).text(function(i, text){
      return text === "Less" ? "More" : "Less";
      })
  });
})
```

HTML:

```
Preview text is here and <span class="toggle" style="display:none;">hidden text is here</span>
<a href="#" id="toggle" class="collapse">More</a>
```

I would need to repeat this for each newsletter preview but don't want each newsletter to need to call a unique function.

I'm sure this is a super simple fix, I just have absolutely zero experience. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your `collapse` class and `$.siblings()`:

```
<p>
    Preview text is here and <span class="toggle" style="display:none;">hidden text is here</span>
    <a href="#" class="collapse">More</a>
</p>

$(function () {
    $('.collapse').click(function () {
        $(this)
            .siblings('.toggle').toggle().end()
            .text(function (i, text) {
                return text === "Less" ? "More" : "Less";
            });

        return false;
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CpUQg/1

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. One more question > I tried changing .toggle to .slideToggle and everything seems to work fine _except_ for the first click. Any ideas why that might be? Otherwise this works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Id of every html element must be unique. You should use class selectors for this job.

Html

```
Preview text is here and <span class="toggle"><span class="toggle-content" style="display:none;">hidden text is here</span>
<a href="#" class="collapse">More</a>
```

Js

```
$(function() {
$('.collapse').click(function() {
    $(this).parent(".toggle").find(".toggle-content").toggle();
    $(this).text(function(i, text){
      return text === "Less" ? "More" : "Less";
      })
    return false;
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n3NLA/